# How to Split Pandas DataFrames Based on a Status Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, slice

I have a DataFrame that looks somehow like the following one:

```
     time  status    A
  0     0       2   20
  1     1       2   21
  2     2       2   20
  3     3       2   19
  4     4      10   18
  5     5       2   17
  6     6       2   18
  7     7       2   19
  8     8       2   18
  9     9      10   17
...   ...     ...  ...
```

Now, I'd like to select all rows with status == 2 and kind of group the resulting rows, that are not interupted by any other row-status so that I can access each group afterwards separately.

Something like:

```
print df1
 
     time  status    A
  0     0       2   20
  1     1       2   21
  2     2       2   20
  3     3       2   19
 
print df2
 
     time  status    A
  0     5       2   17
  1     6       2   18
  2     7       2   19
  3     8       2   18
```

Is there an efficient, loop-avoiding way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think at line 2 of df1, A is 21 not 22.

Comment: You‘re absolutely right, it was mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```py
>>> df
   time  status   A
0     0       2  20  # group 1
1     1       2  21  # 1
2     2       2  20  # 1
3     3       2  19  # 1
4     4      10  18  # group 2
5     5       2  17  # group 3
6     6       2  18  # 3
7     7       2  19  # 3
8     8       2  18  # 3
9     9      10  17  # group 4
```

```py
df["group"] = df.status.ne(df.status.shift()).cumsum()
```

```py
>>> df
   time  status   A  group
0     0       2  20      1
1     1       2  21      1
2     2       2  20      1
3     3       2  19      1
4     4      10  18      2
5     5       2  17      3
6     6       2  18      3
7     7       2  19      3
8     8       2  18      3
9     9      10  17      4
```

Now you can do what you want. For example:

```py
(_, df1), (_, df2) = list(df.loc[df["status"] == 2].groupby("group"))
```

```
>>> df1
   time  status   A  group
0     0       2  20      1
1     1       2  21      1
2     2       2  20      1
3     3       2  19      1

>>> df2
   time  status   A  group
5     5       2  17      3
6     6       2  18      3
7     7       2  19      3
8     8       2  18      3
```